# Cocoapod : Redefining preprocess macro using post install hook

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I want to update my pod to let users activating/desactivating a feature.

To do this I've added a Preprocessor macro in my `podspec` :

```
s.xcconfig         = { 'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS' => 'FEATURE=1' }
```

Now, for a user the right thing to do (of what I've understood) should be to use a post install hook in the `podfile` to change the definition of `FEATURE`

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "Pods-MyPod"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'FEATURE=0']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But it did not do anything at all ... `FEATURE` value is still 1

Am I doing something wrong ?

EDIT :
I did take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133993/why-isnt-my-cocoapods-post-install-hook-updating-my-preprocessor-macros), but it did not help.

Comment: Why is it down voted ? ... Please feel free to explain yourself in the comment and I'll try to update my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end, I found a working version.

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "Pods-MyPod"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = ['COCOAPODS=1', 'FEATURE=0']
      end
    end
  end
end
```